# Listbox item that stretches to width of listbox BUT not past the width

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a listbox that I want to take up the width of my window, and the list box items will stretch to the size of the listbox.

Each listbox item will be a datatemplate that has about 150 width for information and the remaining size to be a textbox for a description. I want the description texbox to stretch to remaining available size. So here is example xaml that I thought would create this layout:

```
<Window x:Class="test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
  <ListBox Margin="20,20,20,20" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=List}">
     <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
           <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                   Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
     </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <Border BorderBrush="AliceBlue"
                   BorderThickness="1">
              <Grid>
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                 <Label Width="20"
                        Content="Test" />
                 <ComboBox Width="130" />
                 <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
              </Grid>
           </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
```

However, when I type in the textbox and the text width goes past the width of the listbox, the listbox item keeps growing and the horizontal scroll bar shows up.

What I want to achieve is the max width of the textbox to go just up to the listbox and not grow wider. Anyone know how I can achieve this layout?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` to `ListBox`, it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your Listbox contains a scrollviewer, which means that its children can have any size they want, the scroll viewer will take care of that. Your ColumnDefinition practically says "Use all the unlimited space we have". 
One solution that comes to my mind would be to bind the Grids Width to the ListBox ActualWidth

```
Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Path=ActualWidth}"
```

but propably better is Dmitrys solution.